# Centering span in table body

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to center `span` in `tbody`, but I am not sure how to do that and I don't know if this structure is valid if I don't include a `tr` and `td` elements.

**html**

```
<table class="table">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Rank</th>
         <th>
            <div>Name</div>
         </th>
         <th>
            <div>Age</div>
         </th>
         <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
         <div><span>You haven’t added any data yet</span></div>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**css**

```
tbody div {
  display: table-row;
}

tbody div span{
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I believe you should be using colspan: https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_td_colspan.asp

Comment: @Neil yes, I totally forgot that this exists. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use colspan:

```
<table class="table">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Rank</th>
         <th>
            <div>Name</div>
         </th>
         <th>
            <div>Age</div>
         </th>
         <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr> 
         <td colspan="3">You haven’t added any data yet</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

By convention you should include tr and th as well within tbody

You can use `colspan` to merge columns and `text-align:center` style to center text.

```
<table class="table" style="width:100%">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Rank</th>
         <th>
            <div>Name</div>
         </th>
         <th>
            <div>Age</div>
         </th>
         <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr> 
         <td colspan="4" style="text-align: center;">You haven’t added any data yet</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```